# Using non-linear regression to remedy serial correlation in Stata

Tags: regression, stata

I am trying to run a non-linear regression in Stata using the nl command. The reason I am running the regression is that my data exhibits serial correlation - AR(1). I use the following command.

```
nl (m = {b0}+  {b1}*lagm + {b2}*y + {b3}*r ({b10})*{b4}*lagy + ({b10})*{b5}*lagy + ({b10})*{b6}*lag2m),  initial(b0 0 b1 0.9 b2 0.09 b3 -0.0055 b4 0 b5 0 b6 0.5 b10 0), if A>2
```

However, I get the error

"error #198 occurred in evaluating expression
invalid '(' 
starting values invalid or some RHS variables have missing values"

I have tried to change the initial values several times and I have, as you can see, made sure that missing values are no problem for the lagged variables.

Best,

Comment: Why not fit something explicitly meant for this DGP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `variables` option. If you don't, then `nl` issues an error message with return code 480 if the estimation sample contains any missing values. That's the second problem.

Your first error code is r(198), so your syntax appears off. The part "{b3}*r ({b10})*{b4}*lagy" is definitely bad (needs some arithmetic operators) and your `if` clause is in the wrong/nonstandard place, though the latter is surprisingly not a problem.

Without knowing more about your data, and exactly what you typed, it's hard to diagnose exactly what's going wrong, but these two fixes should help.

Here's a two reproducible examples, one that works and one that fails:

```
webuse sunspot, clear
tsset time
nl (spot ={b0}+{b1}*L.spot) if time >0, initial(b0 0 b1 0) variables(L.spot)
nl (spot ={b0}+{b1}*L.spot{b3}) if time >0, initial(b0 0 b1 0 b3 0) variables(L.spot)
```

One you `tsset` your data, you can use the lag operator as well instead of creating lags by hand.

You can also fit an AR(1) model like this:

`arima spot, ar(1)`